# How to extract price from table using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a value from a table - in the HTML below how do I extract the FIRST price of £30 using jQuery?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table table-striped" style="margin-bottom: 15px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="cartItem">1 sqft
                    Bundle</span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 20px;">
        <a href="_add_item.php?agent=1&ht_currency=1&&" title="remove item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
      </td>
      <td>&pound;30.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="basket-spacer-row">
      <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Total</th>
      <th>&pound;30.00</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: which price? i suggest you put a  class or ID to the td or th where you want to get the value from.

Comment: and a span perhaps to not have to remove the pound sign. Or use a data-attribute

Comment: I can't change the HTML so I need to extract the price (£30) without changing the HTML but I can run Javascript

Comment: Which price? Total or the other?

Comment: The first price

Comment: `.html()` will give you the HTML content, you need to use `.replace()` to get the numeric contents only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax:

```js
$('.table tr:not(#basket-spacer-row) th:last-child, .table tr:not(#basket-spacer-row) td:last-child').each(function() {
  var price = $(this).html() //this is your value
  console.log(price)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table table-striped" style="margin-bottom: 15px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span class="cartItem">1 sqft
                Bundle</span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 20px;">
        <a href="_add_item.php?agent=1&ht_currency=1&&" title="remove item"><span class=
                    "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
      </td>
      <td>&pound;30.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="basket-spacer-row">
      <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Total</th>
      <th>&pound;30.00</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `var currentElement = $(this)
    currentElement.html()` will do nothing

Comment: Modified to include comment and negate spacer row.

Comment: Tried this but i get this error:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).each is not a function(…)

Comment: Why you don't use `$(this).html()` and declare additional variable?

Comment: @mplungjan - thank you, edited the answer - should work now.

Comment: Yes, better now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the last price, then

`var pounds = $('#basket-spacer-row').next().find('th').last().text();`

First:

`var pounds = $('#basket-spacer-row').prev().find('td').last().text();`

It depends on how dynamic the rendering of this table is. I always prefer ID selectors since they are the most specific. This is not nice, but it works. I select the tr with the id, move to the next sibling and select the text of the last th element within. This looks like the spacer row should always be at the end so this may work in most cases, but again, this type of selectors and navigation is very fragile. You could also check for the £ character and create a logic based on its occurrence.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onzqmpk2/)

Comment: I am afraid the ID might not be unique here. If it is, good idea

Comment: Sorry I should have said the first price i.e. not the Total

Comment: then use prev() and td

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which 30 you are talking about. If you are talking about the first one,

```
var p = $('.table tr:first-child td:last-child').text();
```

or this one:

```
var p = $('.table tr:last-child th:last-child').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax:

```
  $("td:nth-child(1)")
```

For More : [W3School Jquery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/trysel.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prev()` and `find()`

```
$('#basket-spacer-row').prev().find('td:last').text();
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcjjz6da/

Comment: Better add an ID, but he cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()`, to get only numeric value i.e. `30.00`, use `/[^\d.]/g`

`$('.table tr:eq(0) td:eq(2)').html()` will give you the HTML content.

```
var cellValue = $('.table tr:eq(0) td:eq(2)').html();
console.log(cellValue);
yourString = cellValue.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '');
console.log(yourString);
```

```js
var cellValue = $('.table tr:eq(0) td:eq(2)').html();
console.log(cellValue);
yourString = cellValue.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '');
console.log(yourString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped" style=
        "margin-bottom: 15px; table-layout: fixed;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="cartItem">1 sqft
                Bundle</span></td>
                <td style="width: 20px;">
                    <a href="_add_item.php?agent=1&ht_currency=1&&" title=
                    "remove item"><span class=
                    "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
                </td>
                <td>&pound;30.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="basket-spacer-row">
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">Total</th>
                <th>&pound;30.00</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.panel-body').find('table tr').first().find('td').last().text(); //this will give td's £30,
     $('.panel-body').find('table tr').last().find('th').last().text(); //this will give th's £30
});
```